# Does !important not works in IE6?

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

Does `!important` not works in IE6 ? If we need IE6 compatibility too then shouldn't we use `!important`?

Comment: @jitendra - honestly in 726+ questions have you not learned to google? `ie6 important` gives me what the first answer links to. you can cut down half of your questions by simply googling first.

Comment: A specific example where you're having trouble with this would be helpful in providing a more thorough answer, though Graphain has covered the most obvious issues.

Comment: If google does not give good answer then i ask here. if google can find is does not mean question should not asked here. I gain great knowledge from peoples answers on SO even for the same topic there were many articles available in google search. for me many times SO's answer gave me better answer then any articles on any blog.

Comment: you asked "does !important not works in ie6", 1 minute on google would lead you to dozens of articles stating the bugs with it. why not word your question more specifically, or paste a description which you do not understand so others could illuminate what it says for you?

Comment: @Mike Tierney - I just want to know Does IE 6 support !important or not or it's support in a specific way. on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#attributes mentioned "Partial" for support of !important in IE6. I want to know what is that "Partial" support. on this page there is no info about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE6 supports !important when the rule with !important is the last rule for that property within a selector.

This sounds a little confusing, but if you declare an !important height, it must be the last declaration for 'height' within a given selector.

As such consider these examples:

```
#selector { height: 100px; height: 150px !important; }
Result: All browsers: 150px;

#selector { height: 100px; height: 150px !important; }
td#selector { height: 200px; }
Result: All browsers: 150px;

#selector { height: 100px; height: 150px; }
td#selector { height: 70px; height: 200px !important; }
Result: All browsers: 200px;

#selector { height: 100px !important; height: 150px; }
Result: All modern browsers but ie6: 100px; ie6: 150px;

#selector { height: 100px !important; height: 150px; }
td#selector { height: 200px; }
Result: All modern browsers but ie6: 100px; ie6: 200px;

#selector { height: 100px; height: 150px; }
td#selector { height: 70px !important; height: 200px; }
Result: All modern browsers but ie6: 70px; ie6: 200px;
```

What ie6 does is parse the 'height' value for each selector as the last 'height' declaration present within the selector (other rules may apply but I believe this is your standard case). Then it selects the most specific 'height' out of all of these based on !important and selector specificity rules. It effectively ignores the 'height' declarations that are not the last within their selector.

Other browsers instead will take into account '!important' when parsing the 'height' value for each selector, before comparing selectors based on !important and specificity rules.

One "benefit" of this is that every other reasonable browser will use your "important" style, while ie6 will pick the last rule declaration within that selector.

You would be much better off with an ie6 specific stylesheet though unless there is only a *very* small number of ie6 tweaks and you want to css comment each one as an ie6 exploit.

#### Mental Example

Imagine picking a CSS rule is a matter of 1) getting all the rules that match the element and 2) deciding which of those rules to use. Pretend the inline style tag is just another selector unless I mention otherwise.

In every other browser if you want to get the 'height' for an element it does this approximately:

1. For each selector choose the last !important height if there is one, otherwise just the last height.
2. Pick the most specific selector where the selected 'height' is an !important height, otherwise the inline style height, otherwise the most specific selector.

In ie6 it does this approximately:

1. For each selector choose the last height.
2. Pick the most specific selector where the selected 'height' is an !important height, otherwise the inline style height, otherwise the most specific selector.

Comment: This is slightly inaccurate. It works _as long as it's not the last rule declared for that property_ in this selector. In this example, reverse the two `height` rules and you'll see that, indeed, the height is `100px` (even if a different selector would normally have overridden it).

Comment: Actually, that has more to do with the way that the rules are getting interpreted -- the last rule typically wins (lots of hacks are based on this principle).

Comment: Thanks John - I think I assumed as much but was just copying the Googled answer. I've updated my answer to reflect and might clarify it a little more.

Comment: what about cascading and overriding on other rules's properties. which are in different selectors but nested.

Comment: My example already covered that. I added a further clarification of how it selects the rule. Please let me know if this clears things up. Basically there are two issues: 1) which rule is picked per selector and 2) which selector is picked (which is based on 1.) 2) is the same for all browsers, but 1) differs for ie6 (it doesn't always pick the !important rule for a selector which means that selector may not get picked).